# Why even though linking is finished correctly, i get undefined reference error?

Tags: c, linker

I'm trying to learn c and I implemented a bubblesort function and i decided It would be better idea if i made a library that will contain various sorting algorithms, so I compiled my code with this:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o bin/bsort.o sort/Bubblesort.c
```

my bubblesort.c is working (and not related to question at all and there is nothing other than bubblesort function there):
// Licensed under public domain with no warranty

```
void bubblesort(int* array) {
    //implemention goes here
}
```

my sort.h file:

```
void bubblesort(int* array);
```

my nsort.c

```
#include "sort/sort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    int* sortthis = malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        *(sortthis+i) = random(); //random int is defined somewhere else
    }
    

    bubblesort(sortthis);
    for(int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        printf("%d ",*(sortthis+i));
    }
    free(sortthis);
    return 0;
}
```

my script that i use to compile:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o bin/bsort.o sort/Bubblesort.c
gcc nsort.c sort/sort.h -Lbin/bsort.o -lm -o demo.elf
```

what could be i'm doing wrong, i tried various things but it didn't work, i kept getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxhd5zd.o: in function `main':
nsort.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `bubblesort'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

gcc --version (just in case if there is a bug in this version):

```
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

Comment: `bubblesort(sortthis,1000);` does not match `void bubblesort(int* array);` different args

Comment: it was from old code @pm100 let me edit it i have still the error

Comment: Also `gcc nsort.c sort/sort.h -Lbin/bsort.o -lm -o demo.elf` should be `gcc nsort.c sort/sort.c -Lbin/bsort.o -lm -o demo.elf`, you need to compile the .c not the .h

Comment: compilation of .h file was one of things i have tried for no reason i said "maybe it will work", and there is no sort.c file btw

Comment: is there's a way to force compiler compile anyways it links successfuly i believe but still throws up that error

Comment: If your `bubblesort` function only accepts a pointer to int, and no further argument, then how does it know the size of the array to be sorted?

Comment: `-L` is followed by a directory name, not a filename. It adds that directory to the places that `-l` searches for directories.

Comment: well for testing purposes i set it up to a fixed length @printf

Comment: tried `gcc nsort.c sort/sort.h -Lbin -lbsort.o -lm -o demo.elf` got `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbsort.o` @Barmar (i also tried giving the actual path /home/username/Desktop/learnc/bin/)

Comment: `-l` looks for libraries, not object files. `-lfoo` searches for a library named `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so` (depending on whether you're doing static or shared linking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put `-L` before the `.o` file. `-L` is for adding directories that `-l` searches for libraries.

To link with an object file, just add it as an ordinary file argument.

You also don't need to include header files in the compiler arguments. The compiler reads them when it sees `#include`.

```
gcc nsort.c bin/bsort.o -lm -o demo.elf
```